# how much I can improve in 3 months

Tags: exercise, exercise-frequency

```
173cm - 67 kg
```

I can do

```
50kg Bench Press (40kg if I do alone)
40kg Incline Bench Press
12kg Alternate Hammer Curl
10kg Alternating Deltoid Raise 
10kg Front Two-Dumbbell Raise
```

I do these twice a week(should I increase frequency?) I use whey protein.
I want drop 3 kg fat and gain 3-5 kg muscle.(~70kg) (how easy this goal?)

do you suggest some other exercises? and in 3 months how much I can improve these all(in kg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends a lot on how long you've been training, and what level of technique you have right now.

Assuming you can make some technical gains as well as strength wise gains, and assuming you're quite new to lifting I'd say you can increase by about 15-25% in 3 months, i.e. bench 60-65 kg etc.

I would suggest including leg exercises and avoiding the isolation exercises (hammer curls, raises) and also include some back exercises.

My favourites:

- Bench press
- Squats
- Leg press
- Chin-ups/lat pulldowns
- Rows of all kinds
- Military press
- Deadlifts

Deadlifts and squats are both quite technical and should not be done if you're not very confident you have the right technique, but are very effective if you do.

I prefer these exercises since you save time by training multiple muscles at once (rows: back + biceps) and because you'll be training a movement that you might actually use in real life.

Answer (score 0):

Those are great recommendations for exercises. Stick with the compound multi joint lifts for 80-90% percent of your training. How much you gain is highly individual; training age, sleep, diet and genetics play a big role in that. Eat more carbs on the days you train (especially post workout) and cut them back on the days you don't. Training only twice a week will make it difficult to get stronger and add mass. You need to up your volume (number of sets/reps)  and up your training frequency to 3 or 4 days a week. Start tracking your progress each session. By a log book and write down your reps, sets and the corresponding loads. It is the best thing I ever did. That way you can actually see your progress over a period of time.